# Updating Mysql from adobe flex application

Tags: mysql, apache-flex, adobe, blazeds

Hey there,
I am very new to Flex. I want to build an application that will contain many radio buttons. I want to know how to update mysql by the status of radio buttons.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use one of these MySQL connectors.
There are plenty of reasons not to use them, but the main one is about security issues.

Anyone can decompile your application and see what's inside it. That means having access to all database requests!

Flex is for presentation, you keep business logic and data storage on the server. You would need to have something running on the server that access your database and expose its data as services. There are many possibilities depending which server language you know

Answer (score 1):

Use [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS)/Java to update Database this post contains some usefull links
[Flex 4 BlazeDS with Hibernate and MySQL database](http://www.flexdeveloper.eu/forums/tutorials-examples-and-tools/flex-4-blazeds-with-hibernate-and-mysql-database/)

Hopes that helps

Answer (score 0):

Purchase Flex Connector for MySQL and you will be off and running when you read how to use it.